# ActionBar disappears when changing background color

Tags: android, xml, styles, android-actionbar, themes

I have modified styles.xml in values-v14 to this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BlueWhiteActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueWhiteActionBarTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:background">#0089CD</item>
</style>
```

But if I run the application with this modification the ActionBar disappears, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BlueWhiteActionBarTheme</item>
  </style>

 <style name="BlueWhiteActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:background">#0089CD</item>
 </style>
```

and apply to activity as

```
 android:theme="@style/BlueWhiteActionBarTheme"
```